# C - htoi function

Tags: c, numbers, hex

I'm trying to write a `htoi` function in `C` reading a stream of hex digits, including the leading `0x` or `0X`, and returning the corresponding numerical value.

Can someone help me find out what's wrong with my `htoi` function? It appears that it only works with integers (0-9) for hex and not with 'A'/'a' - 'F'/'f'. I am just curious what's the issue with my code.

For example in I put 'Ox777' I get the number 1911, which is correct, but, if I put the value 'Ox7DF' I get the wrong digit value: it doesn't process the letters, only the numerical characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define YES 1
#define No 1

int htoi(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;

    if (s[i] == '0')
    {
        ++i;
    }

    if (s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 'X')
    {
        ++i;    
    }

    int n = 0; 
    int hexdigit; 

    for(; i < strlen(s); ++i ) 
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'){
            hexdigit = s[i] - '0';
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F'){
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'A' + 10;
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f'){
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'a' + 10;
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }

    printf("%d", n);
    return n;


}

int main() 
{

    char a[] = "0x71927";
    htoi(a);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't Python--you need braces around your block after the `for()`, not just indents.

Answer (score 3):

You have a missing set of curly braces after your `for` statement! As it stands, the body of the loop is ***only*** the following code:

```c
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            hexdigit = s[i] - '0';
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
```

This is because, without a `{`...`}` delimited block *immediately* following the `for` statement, then only a ***single statement*** is used for the loop (and this 'single statement' is the entire first `if` block). Adding the relevant `{` on the `for` line (or on the line after it, if you prefer) and the corresponding `}` *after* your third `if` block fixes the code:

```c
    for (; i < strlen(s); ++i) { // Note the added "{" - which 'starts' the loop's block!
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            hexdigit = s[i] - '0';
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F') {
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'A' + 10;
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f') {
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'a' + 10;
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
    } // And this "}" closes the loop!
```

In your code, there is no test for the "A..F" and "a..f" characters *inside* the loop, so any such in the hex number will be ignored (treated as zero). When the two subsequent `if` tests are executed, `s[i]` will be pointing to the `nul` terminator of the string.

Answer (score 0):

interesting, why

```c
hexdigit = s[i] - '0'; n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
```

```c
for(; i < strlen(s); ++i ) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'){
/*->*/       hexdigit = s[i] - '0';
/*->*/       n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F'){
/*->*/      hexdigit = s[i] - 'A' + 10;
/*->*/      n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f'){
/*->*/      hexdigit = s[i] - 'a' + 10;
/*->*/      n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
}
```

in this construction, can't just do that

```
// from ASCII 'a' = 97
hexdigit = (int) s[i]-86;
or
s[i] =(int) s[i] -86;
```

Comment: `'a'` isn't necessarily `97`. [Can be `129`](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/cmsc311/clin-cmsc311/Lectures/lecture6/ebcdic.html) or something else :-)

Comment: yes can, but i tell about ASCII

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it function without the set of curly braces after your for statement then the if blocks should function as if...else ladder as the following code:

```
 for(; i < strlen(s); ++i ) 
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'){
            hexdigit = s[i] - '0';
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        } else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F'){
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'A' + 10;
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        } else if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f'){
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'a' + 10;
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
```